# w3c validation error in xslt

Tags: html, xslt

My xsl file is like:

```
<img> 
     <xsl:attribute name="id">poster_<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>      
     <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="movie-title"/></xsl:attribute>     
     <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="../poster-verylarge-image"/><xsl:value-of    select="movie-photo-name"/></xsl:attribute> 
</img>
```

And I am getting a W3C error as:

> Line 508, Column 234: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified
>   …artini.com/user_uploads/moviereview/420_265/7876579_1342029293_79940.jpeg">

Please help me out.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in that snippet, can you post the complete XSLT?

Comment: Is it the XSLT that you validating, or the output from your XSLT (i.e HTML)?

Comment: @TimC :Am validating output of xslt that is html.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shown the full XSLT, or the output HTML, I suspect that in your XSLT document you have specified the output be HTML

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#output) website:

> The html output method should not output an end-tag for empty
>   elements. For HTML 4.0, the empty elements are area, base, basefont,
>   br, col, frame, hr, img, input, isindex, link, meta and param. For
>   example, an element written as `<br/>` or `<br></br>` in the stylesheet
>   should be output as `<br>`.

In your small sample you are outputing an image tag, which will probably be output as follows:

```
<img id="img1" src="test.html" alt="test">
```

If you are validating your document as XHTML using the W3C validator, this will fail as the image tag is not closed. When it is an XHTML document it means the HTML must also conform to being a well-formed XML document.

There a number of ways to resolve this. Firstly, if you are using XSLT2.0, you can specify an output method of xhtml, and this should close the tags

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml" />
```

Alternatively, as XHTML should be well-formed XML, you could just specify an output method of xml. This will still output the HTML you require, but it will also be well-formed XML.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" />
```

However, it might be preferable to specify the doctype of the output html, so that the W3C validator knows exactly what version of HTML it is validating. For example:

```
<xsl:output method="html" 
   doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" />
```

When you do this, an HTML document with non-closed tags should validate

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Test</title></head>
<body><img id="img1" src="test.html" alt="test"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The doctype is like dis:  <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  <br/>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb">

Comment: If you aren't able to change the doc type, then try changing the output method to "xml" like so `<xsl:output method="xml" />`

Comment: But i want results in html not in xml.  For example: try validating www.desimartini.com on w3c validator. You will get some errors like:  Line 508, Column 234: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Comment: You are currently validating it as XHTML, so the HTML must also be well-formed XML document. Changing the output method as XML will still output the HTML. Alternatively change the DOCTYPE, as described in the answer, so that it validates as HTML not XHTML.

Comment: Thank You so much. I have implemented it and it seems that it's working.

Comment: <xsl:output method="xhtml" /> This is causing render problems in some xsl pages.